# What's wrong with my php/sqli update query? (Update query can't read customer_ID correctly)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-update

I'm a beginner in php/mysqli.  I've been trying to create a form that allows users to update customer data. I believe my php code is correct, but every time I make changes to a customer, all the new data is shown in the record of the first customer in the dataset. Can you take a look at my code below and give me some guidance on what I'm missing? Thanks!

Here is part of the main.php file

```
<div>
            <form method="post" action="updatecustomer.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Update Existing Customer</legend>
                    <li>Customer ID:    
                    <select name="customer_id">
        <?php
        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT customer_id, customer_id FROM customer"))){
            echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            echo "Execute failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
        if(!$stmt->bind_result($customer_id, $customer_id)){
            echo "Bind failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            echo '<option value=" '. $customer_id . ' "> ' . $customer_id . '</option>\n';
        }
        $stmt->close();
        ?>
                    </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>First Name: <input type="text" name="fName"> Last Name: <input type="text" name="lName"</li>
                    <li>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"></li>
                    <li>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone_number"></li>
                    <li>Street Number: <input type="text" name="address_no"> Street Line 1: <input type="text" name="address_street1"></li>
                    <li>Street Line 2 (Apt or Unit Number): <input type="text" name="address_street2"></li>
                    <li>City: <input type="text" name="address_city"> State: <input type="text" name="address_state"> Zip: <input type="text" name="address_zip"> </li> 
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Customer">
        </div>
```

Here is the updatecustomer.php

```
    <?php

if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE customer SET fName=?, lName=?, email=?, phone_number=?, address_no=?, address_street1=?, 
    address_street2=?, address_city=?, address_state=?, address_zip=? WHERE customer_id=?"))){
    echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}

if(!($stmt->bind_param("sssiissssii",$_POST['fName'],$_POST['lName'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['phone_number'], $_POST['address_no'],
    $_POST['address_street1'],$_POST['address_street2'],$_POST['address_city'],$_POST['address_state'], $_POST['address_zip'], $_POST['customer_id']))){
    echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}
if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo "Execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
} else {
    echo "Updated " . $stmt->affected_rows . " rows to customer.";
    echo $_POST['customer_id'];

}


$stmt->close();


?>
```

Comment: Yeah! whats wrong with your query?

Comment: Please track down the error, and post only the relevant part of the code. That way you'll get more attention.

Comment: not very sure on error, but why you have customer_id twice in your select list, and then you are binding the same variable twice. I guess you are doing something wrong there. Even if you need to print Customer ID twice you can still use same variable twice, so why bind it again and again.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you bind your own defined variables as parameters instead of the actual $_POST data.

```
if($stmt->bind_param("sssiissssii",$fname,$lname$email, ... ,$customerid))
{
 $fname = $_POST['fname'];
 $lname = $_POST['lname'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 ...
 $customerid = $_POST['customer_id'];
} 
else
{
  //error message here then exit
}
```

It has something to do with the internals of the bind_param method.
Please give it a try then let me know how it goes.

Also, the way you test you do error handling in updatecustomer.php could use some changes. If the prepare statement fails, its already a given that everything after it will fail. Same goes for the succeeding method calls. They will fail if the method before them fails, might be better if you exit() after printing the error message to reduce the mess your code makes.

Comment: Hi. I tried to change my code based on your suggestions.  It still doesn't work.  When I select ID #3 in the drop down box and modify my data, the changes go to ID #1.  Nothing changes in ID #3.

Comment: can you try `echo $_POST['customer_id'];` before you bind the parameters then run that. just to make sure that you are passing the correct id to the query.

Comment: I just tried that. It prints out "1" when I select "3" in my form.  I believe I'm not passing the correct id to the query, but I can't tell what I'm missing in the main.php code.  Any suggestions? I've been stuck at this for hours.